# pathos package in windows Operating System

Tags: python, windows, package, pathos

Hie , can any one tell me how can i install pathos package of python in windows OS. I wanted to to install pathos in windows OS. I got an error for pickling and un pickling,

Answer (score 1):

I'm the pathos author.  This worked for me:

> - installed Visual Studio Community 2015 RC
> - installed Python Tools 2.2 RC for Visual Studio 2015
> - installed Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7
> - installed Miniconda 3.10.1 (64-bit) for Python 2.7
> - installed Git for Windows 1.9.5-preview20150319
> - conda install pip
> - conda install setuptools
> - pip install git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos.git@master

`pathos` is pure python, however one of it's dependencies requires a `C` compiler, and you can use the free MSVC.

Comment: Note: the above instructions will install the "bleeding edge" code from the `pathos` git repository.  If you want to install the latest release, you can replace the last step with "`pip install pathos …`" as mentioned in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issues when installing the pathos package on Windows 10. What worked for me was following the procedure described by [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33313703/1193136) until the last step, that I replaced with the following:

```
pip install pathos --no-cache-dir
```

To prevent pip from going to the cache.